# How to adjust the brightness of the screen on notebook displays

Tags: windows, winapi, brightness

I have a slide bar to adjust the brightness of the screen on notebook displays in my application, but I found those articles from internet are adjusting the Gamma value, the behavior is not really like pressing the special key in keyboard. Is there a way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Here is some links what I found.

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/gamma_manager.aspx?display=PrintAll
- http://mycomponent.blogspot.com/2009/05/set-screen-brightness-in-c.html
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sidebargadfetdevelopment/thread/8fd043fd-79fb-4d91-ad17-0d109f893331

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373297/what-api-call-would-i-use-to-change-brightness-of-laptop-net

Comment: `notebook` tag removed as part of the [2012 cleanup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012).

Answer (score 1):

Very unikely that there is a way to do it with software - it's probably controlled by the laptops BIOS, which windows will not have hooks into.

Comment: If you're targeting a specific laptop platform, you might be able to interact with the mfg's driver or helper applications. But overall I agree with this statement.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is for Linux you could see how the Screen Brightness applet works by looking at the code.