# How to turn off particular monitor with .NET?

Tags: c#, screen, monitor

OK, I know there are quite a few posts on this topic. However, none of them provide the solution to my issue: I don't want just to turn off my monitor(s), I wish my code to turn off **a specific** monitor. The URL the most people refer to, http://fci-h.blogspot.com/2007/03/turn-off-your-monitor-via-code-c.html, doesn't help here, as it turns off all the displays.

So, I have my laptop screen and an additional external monitor. While I'm watching movies, I switch the display to the external monitor and my laptop screen goes black, however, it's still on and glowing in the dark. I wish to turn it off. Could anyone help please?

**EDIT:** Is there any way to acomplish this, meaning it needn't have to be written in .Net. Basically, I just need an .exe file that's able to turn the particular monitor off and on alternately.

Comment: @omfgroflmao - I don't know about yours, but my laptop's on/off button turns off the CPU when it turns off the screen, so it's not too useful.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: not c#, but maybe this can help you if you're willing to search for more material in c++: http://www.codeproject.com/kb/system/display_states.aspx

Comment: Not *quite* a dupe, but cross-reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713498/turn-on-off-monitor

Comment: @gabe: I'm using Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: @omfgroflmao: Hahahahaha, nice one. However, my laptop lacks that functionality.

Comment: @zxcvbnm and @Marc Gravell: Thanks for the links, however, they don't really solve the main issue - turning off *particular* monitor.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like there's no good way of turning off a specific monitor, but it is possible to set your laptop's backlight to minimum brightness. Depending on which version of Windows you have, there are different ways to do it:

- [send IOCTL_VIDEO_SET_DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS I/O control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372704(v=VS.85).aspx) as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dvdarchive/cc163415.aspx
- use WMI method [WmiSetBrightness](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394549.aspx) as described here: [What API call would I use to change brightness of laptop (.NET)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373297/what-api-call-would-i-use-to-change-brightness-of-laptop-net/799207#799207)
- use Win API [SetMonitorBrightness](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd692972(VS.85).aspx), but I don't know of anybody who has done it in C#.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If no solution turns up, it appears that I'd have to satisfy myself with lowering the brightness.