# How to change laptop screen brightness from a java application?

Tags: java, windows, brightness

I want to create a java application to change the laptop screen brightness on windows xp/7. Please help

Answer (score 7):

As others have stated, there isn't any official API to use. However, using Windows Powershell (which comes with windows I believe, so no need to download anything) and [WmiSetBrightness](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394549%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), one can create a simple workaround that should work on all windows PCs with visa or later installed.

All you need to do is copy this class into your workspace:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class BrightnessManager {
    public static void setBrightness(int brightness)
            throws IOException {
        //Creates a powerShell command that will set the brightness to the requested value (0-100), after the requested delay (in milliseconds) has passed. 
        String s = String.format("$brightness = %d;", brightness)
                + "$delay = 0;"
                + "$myMonitor = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\\wmi -Class WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods;"
                + "$myMonitor.wmisetbrightness($delay, $brightness)";
        String command = "powershell.exe  " + s;
        // Executing the command
        Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        powerShellProcess.getOutputStream().close();

        //Report any error messages
        String line;

        BufferedReader stderr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                powerShellProcess.getErrorStream()));
        line = stderr.readLine();
        if (line != null)
        {
            System.err.println("Standard Error:");
            do
            {
                System.err.println(line);
            } while ((line = stderr.readLine()) != null);

        }
        stderr.close();

    }
}
```

And then call

```
BrightnessManager.setBrightness({brightness});
```

Where {brightness} is the brightness you want to set the screen display at with 0 being the dimmest supported brightness and 100 being the brightest.

Big thanks to anquegi for the powershell code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545611/executing-powershell-commands-in-java-program) that I adapted to run this command.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.It gives this error on Windows `10->Standard Error:
Get-WmiObject : Not supported 
At line:1 char:42
+ ... myMonitor = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\wmi -Class WmiMonitorBright ...
+`

Comment: Resume->
   `+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:111
+ ... torBrightnessMethods;$myMonitor.wmisetbrightness($delay, $brightness)
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a standard API do do that in Java.

But it seems that you can do it in .NET in windows. See:
[What API call would I use to change brightness of laptop (.NET)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373297/what-api-call-would-i-use-to-change-brightness-of-laptop-net)

You can always use a JNI interface to call a native method written in C++ - so this might be a workaround.