# Any cross-platform method to change the brightness/contrast of the monitor display?

Tags: c++, brightness, contrast

I spent several hours on Google, but in vain. Is there any library or something which can reduce the brightness of the screen ? Or the contrast, or maybe add some tint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are OS-specific interfaces that you can use (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373297/what-api-call-would-i-use-to-change-brightness-of-laptop-net) for one option using WMI), but there is nothing that will remain the same across all OS platforms.